QGIS: Saving a custom Python function from the Function Editor to OPKG/QML
As the title states, I'm trying to save a style to OPKG or QML.
The problem is that I have used a custom Python function within the 'Function Editor' in the symbol section, which is currently not appended when saving the style.
Does anyone know a way to deal with that?

Saving your function has nothing to do with saving the style, I'm not sure if you can save a function to the database (it would be a security nightmare if nothing else)
